# Regex to capturing key/values

Tags: java, regex

I have an output of a command that basically lists a bunch of key/value pairs inside of it. The output is in no obvious format, therefore I think regex will be the best approach.

Output: http://pastebin.com/Hfu4nP3M

Basically, I need to store the key/value pairs (comma seperated) from lines 21-30 and store them in a  map.

Is it possible to do this using regex?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like JSON... if it is, it is not recommended you use regular expressions...

Comment: It doesn't validate as JSON, because of the unquoted strings :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you want, but since you said that you need to store the key/value pairs (comma seperated) from lines 21-30 which are

```
 {memory,
     [{total,38751504},
      {processes,13711212},
      {processes_used,13711198},
      {system,25040292},
      {atom,662409},
      {atom_used,653371},
      {binary,287088},
      {code,18209655},
      {ets,1358504}]},
```

I assumed that you want to read values after `memory` that are stored inside `[...]`.

To do this you can use something like

```
//creating reader to get data from file
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream("data.txt")));// file with your data

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line.trim());// also remove unnecessary tabulators and
                            // spaces
}
in.close();

String data = sb.toString();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{memory,\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
if (m.find()) {
    Pattern keyValuePattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w*?),(\\d*?)\\}");
    Matcher matcher = keyValuePattern.matcher(m.group(1));
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "->" + matcher.group(2));
} else
    System.out.println("not found");
```

Output

```
total->38751504
processes->13711212
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might need some cleaning up -- I don't work with regex often, and never in Java.

Try using the Regex:

```
[{,][^",}]*?[,}]
```

That is: Find a character equal to '{' or ',', then find infinite characters that are not '"', '}' or ',' until you find a character equal to '}' or ','.

To find everything that isn't already marked with quotes, match it.

```
String s = p.match();
s = s.charAt(0) + '"' + s.substring(1, s.length() - 1) + '"' + s.charAt(s.length() - 1;
```

Then put that back into your log at the proper position. After you've finished all of them, you can use JSON to read the log.

Also, you'll probably want to have your log in memory, so it will be easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the output line by line until you find '{memory' using String.equals() is ok.
Then on all following lines you can do

```
    String[] result = line.replaceAll("[\\[\\]}{ \t]|},", "").split(",");
    System.out.println(result[0] + "," + result[1]);
    if(line.contains("]"))
        break;
```